# Scrollbar appears on full screen while CTRL +

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have some divs and I want that when I get the screen bigger(CTRL +) , the scrollbar appears at the bottom of the page and the divs STAY inline block. I have the code here(**http://fiddle.jshell.net/JNzFp/**) and as you can see when you get the screen bigger , scrollbar appears under the divs and I want it to display on the bottom of the full screen not under the divs, and ALSO I don't want vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Hiding scrollbars can be achieved using `overflow-y:hidden;` or `overflow-x:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS `overflow:hidden`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zCxhK/

Below is a demo of the different overflow properties.

UPDATE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Please do not use w3schools as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bar appears in `#menu` div because you have used `overflow: auto` in its css. Use `hidden` instead of `auto` for not allowing scrollbar to appear below the divs

**UPDATE-** For that you have to make your `menu` div 100% of the body

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JNzFp/4/)**

**CSS -**

```
 #menu{
white-space:nowrap;
 overflow:auto; 
width:100%;
 /*height:40px;*/
height: 100%;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0 0 12;
 background:url(file:///C:/Users/Windows7/Desktop/imgbg.jpg) repeat 0 0 #f8f8f8;
 border:1 solid;
 border-width:0 1 1;...
```

Comment: But I want a scrollbar to the divs in the menu, I only want it in the bottom of the page

Comment: for that case your `menu` div should be 100% of the `body`